# How to implement an entangled measurement in mathematica?

Tags: quantum-computing

Suppose, we have two states $|\phi^+\rangle_{AB},|\phi^+\rangle_{CD}$. Now a Bell basis measurement is performed on the qubits BC. How to code in Mathematica to find out the post-measurement state on qubits AD after the Bell measurement is performed on the qubits BC?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you using an external package or an existing framework for quantum computing?

Comment: There is a quantum package by the Wolfram team (I did not try it) that mentions entanglement https://resources.wolframcloud.com/PacletRepository/resources/Wolfram/QuantumFramework/

Comment: For project-based questions, you can also try your luck on the wolfram notebook repository such as these maybe relevant notebooks https://notebookarchive.org/search?q=entanglement, On Github: such as maybe this one https://github.com/emlynsg/hybrid-bell-tests. In the wolfram community forum: https://community.wolfram.com/search?p_p_id=search_WAR_searchportlet&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_col_pos=3&p_p_col_count=4&_search_WAR_searchportlet_filter=&_search_WAR_searchportlet_start=0&_search_WAR_searchportlet_limit=20&_search_WAR_searchportlet_mvcPath=%2Fsearch.jsp&keywords=entanglement

Comment: also a Google search https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=entanglement+mathematica

Comment: Just as a level of conversation check: Did you read e.g.
https://cs.stanford.edu/people/trevisan/quantum/lecture02.pdf